# Executing jQuery dialog associated to class from code behind

Tags: jquery, vb.net, code-behind

Everywhere I've looked shows examples of how to execute a jQuery dialog from code behind, using a #name format, but I've been unable to find guidance as to how to execute a jQuery dialog when the dialog is created as a class.

My scenario is the following: vb.net web app with gridview to present data. When the user clicks a button in a row, instead of editing the row directly in the gridview, I want to open a jQuery dialog, showing the current row data.

On code behind, I populate the textboxes associated to the DIV that should be associated with the jQuery dialog. All good up to now.

My problem is that the form really has several gridviews for displaying data, and several of them requiere to edit the data in a dialog box. So instead of creating a jQuery dialog for each gridview I need edit for, I created just 1 jQuery dialog associated to a class.

The jQuery is the following:

```
function FadingDialogAttachmentOpen(vDivId, vWidth) {
    $('#' + vDivId).dialog("open");
    if (vWidth == null) { vWidth = 300 };
    $('#' + vDivId).dialog("option", "width", vWidth);
    return false;
};

function FadingDialogAttachmentClose(vDivId) {
    $('#' + vDivId).dialog("close");
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.FadingDialog').dialog({
        dialogClass: 'dialog_xms',
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        close: false,
        dragabble: true,
        resizable: false,
        show: 'fade',
        hide: 'fade',
        width: 300,

        open: function (type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo('form');
        },

        buttons: {
            Cancelar: function () {
                f_tcalCancel();
                var a = this;
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            Ok: function () {
                var a = this;
                var btnId = $(this).attr('data-idButton');
                $(this).dialog("close");

                $('#MainContent_' + btnId).click();
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Form code behind, I use the following: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Popup", "FadingDialogAttachmentOpen('dialogEditPayments',500);", True)`

My problem is tha the "open" is firing before the dialog is created. If I change the code in the jQuery to a #name format, the dialog does show up.

Any ideas will be GREATLY appreciated.

Regards, Ariel

Answer (score 0):

I finally figures this one out. It is actually quite simple to achieve. I thought I'd share it, in case anybody else faces the same proble. The final solution is as follows:

1. The javascript functions to initialize/show/hide the dialogs is exactly as shown above
2. Add 2 buttons; each button will raise one of the dialog boxes
3. The HTML to create the DIVs that are used as content for the dialog box is as follows:

   ```
   <div id="ThisIsATest1" class="FadingDialog" title="Dialog Box Example 1">
       This is a test
   </div>
   <div id="ThisIsATest2" class="FadingDialog" title="Dialog Box Example 2" 
       data-idButton="btnDialog">
       This is another test
   </div>
   ```
4. From code behind for each button, use the following sentence:

   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Popup", "$(function()
   {$('.FadingDialog').dialog();FadingDialogAttachmentOpen('" & pDivId & "'," & pWidth.ToString 
   & ");});", True)
5. Replace pDivId with the ID of the corresponding DIV to show; replace pWith.ToString with the width you want the dialog to be
6. Alternatively, you can place the same sentence in a Module, and call a sub that places the clientscript instruction for you (so you don't have to do it for every dialog) like the following:

   ```
   Public Sub fxDialogBox(pDivId As String, pWidth As Integer)
       Dim vPage As Page = HttpContext.Current.Handler
       vPage.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Popup", "$(function()
       {$('.FadingDialog').dialog();FadingDialogAttachmentOpen('" & pDivId & "'," &
       pWidth.ToString & ");});", True)
   End Sub
   ```
7. In each buttons code behind, you would call the function like this: `fx.fxDialogBox("ThisIsATest2", 700)`

Enjoy